# Is there a way to implement a StringBuilder in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112158/javascript-string-concatenation)
>   [does javascript have a built in stringbuilder class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087522/does-javascript-have-a-built-in-stringbuilder-class)

As it's known when we do `str = str + "123"` a new string is created. If we have a large number of concatenations it can be rather expensive. Is there a simple way to implement a StringBuilder in JavaScript?

Comment: strings are immutable is JS, what do you mean by string builder ? like in C# ?

Comment: There's a post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112158/javascript-string-concatenation about string catenation techniques.

Comment: @camus, yes I'm thinking of `StringBuilder` like in C#

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can push the parts into an array, and then join it:

```
var builder = []
builder.push( "some", "123" );
builder.push( "content" );
var str = builder.join("");
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087522/does-javascript-have-a-built-in-stringbuilder-class) explains it in detail, see also [this class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12375/JavaScript-StringBuilder)

Comment: I prefer the more concise notation: `var str = ['some', '123', 'content'].join('');` (usually with line breaks between items)

Answer (score 1):

I think, it's never really simple to implement a StringBuilder that is faster than normal string concatenations. And that's obviously the reason for the Builder.

Fill an array an if it's full convert it to string.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional concatenation in JavaScript is optimal if the strings are static.

```
var foo = 'a' + 'b' + 'c' + 'd';
```

this is true in most browsers. [string-concatenation](http://jsperf.com/string-concatenation)

If the strings may be variable according to the program either method is equally efficient.

```
var foo = ""+Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random();
var foo = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()].join('');
```

the differences are not too great between browsers, but the traditional way seems a little better [string-random-concatenation](http://jsperf.com/string-random-concatenation)