# Convert a large ArrayBuffer into hexadecimal string representation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

I have an `ArrayBuffer` with content that needs to be converted to a hex-string, that should be sent in a JSON message. The data can be up to 2 GB. For this I would like to have a string that works as a dynamic array, so I efficiently could `push_back` individual characters. In C++, we have `std::string` (or `std::vector`), I think Java has a `StringBuilder`. What is the way of doing it in JavaScript?

I tried `+=` but that starts to take minutes after reaching 128 MB. I guess this is because it results in an O(n^2) algorithm.

Note: I also need to do the inverse operation.

Comment: You could build an array (each index being a single two-character string) and then `.join()` it, but 2 gigabytes (well, 8 once it's turned into a hex string, which really means 10 because the buffer is still there) is going to be pretty taxing on the machine.

Comment: Seems like a streaming solution would be a much better idea.

Comment: `+=` normally is optimised by JS engines into a constant average operation, but I guess this might break down when working with humongous strings. As Pointy suggested, do not build the message as a single string value but rather write it into a stream.

Comment: Related: *[JavaScript does not need a StringBuilder](https://josephmate.github.io/java/javascript/stringbuilder/2020/07/27/javascript-does-not-need-stringbuilder.html)*, *[Does JavaScript have a built-in stringbuilder class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087522/does-javascript-have-a-built-in-stringbuilder-class)*, and *[How can I build/concatenate strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845895/how-to-build-concatenate-strings-in-javascript)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen The answer to that question is *probably*. However to make a robust interface that does not expose problems with variable byte length may be difficult. But, having an efficient StringBuilder causes people to think about time complexity, which by itself is good for developing programming skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, why not use a temporary Uint8Array, like so:

```js
function to_hex_string(bytes)
{
    let tmp = new Uint8Array(2*bytes.length);
    for(let k = 0; k != bytes.length; ++k)
    {
        let value = bytes[k];
        let msb = value >> 4;
        let lsb = value & 0xf;
        tmp[2*k] = msb < 10 ? msb + 48 : (msb - 10) + 65;
        tmp[2*k + 1] = lsb < 10 ? lsb + 48 : (lsb - 10) + 65;
    }

    return new TextDecoder().decode(tmp);
}
```

This outperforms joining an array. Though it fails when trying to convert the array to a string when trying 512 MiB. I guess there is some hardcoded limit. Maybe a JS process may not use more than 4 GiB because of a 32-bit VM.